# Cordova: Keyboard events when using external barcode reader with keyboard emulation

Tags: javascript, android, events, cordova, keyboard

I´m developing an android app with cordova latest version to use an android device with a Barcode reader connected through USB with keyboard emulation data transfer. I'm trying to handle the keydown events triggered by the barcode reader every time it reads a code, but the system fires the handle function but i can't find the event data telling me the keycodes.

I'm using that code on application starting:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',
    function(e){
    //Here should come the data but e.keycode everytimes comes with 0
});
```

AS I'm saying on the above code the event var (e) always come with no information about the event triggered, is like a regular event object but comes with no relevant info about the key event.

I will be very gratefull with any help or suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have done this with PG and a barcode scanning device:

Placeholder & timer:

```
var scannerdata = '';
var timer = null;
```

The main function:

```
function getInput (e) {
        scannerdata += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if(timer != null) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function() { setInput() }, 100);
}

function setInput () {
   //add scanner data to input field::
   $('#someInput').val(scannerdata);
   scannerdata = '';

   //OR pass scanner data to function
   someOtherfunction(scannerdata);
   scannerdata = '';
}
```

Event used:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', getInput, false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel kind of retarded :) I've been trying with my college the whole day and we couldn't figure it out.  Againg, THANK YOU

Comment: I am using a PM550 as the barcode scanner device and I am running a Cordova application on the device. I am using an inappbrowser application on top of Cordova application. How can I catch the event and send it to the inappbrowser application?